# Can yadcf server side use column names rather than index?

Tags: yadcf

I am about to get started with server side dataTables / yadcf for a large table.

I see http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html which uses column index.

Since dataTables mostly supports column name for maintainability, is column name an option for yadcf as well?

To be clear, I am talking about using name on the server-client interface, e.g., something like

```
//"yadcf_data_engine":["KHTML","Webkit","Trident","Misc","Other browsers","Tasman","Presto","Gecko"],
```

instead of

```
//"yadcf_data_0":["KHTML","Webkit","Trident","Misc","Other browsers","Tasman","Presto","Gecko"],
```

I can probably kludge something if this is not available, but seems like this is normal need so I am thinking it might already exist.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet :| , there is an [open issue](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/154) about that, you can subscribe to it in order to get updated, a PR is welcome :)